# ES6 default and named exports

Tags: javascript, export, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I am trying to understand named and default exports. I have a seemingly basic requirement which I don't understand how to setup.

I want to be able to import both:

```
//app.js
import Mod from './my-module'
import { funcA, funcB } from './my-module'

console.log('A', Mod.funcA(), funcA()); // A a a
console.log('B', Mod.funcB(), funcB()); // A a a
```

When I try, the closest way of doing this I get to is the following:

```
//my-module.js
export function funcA() { return 'a'; };
export function funcB() { return 'b'; };

export default {funcA, funcB}
```

My trouble is that I don't want to reindex each functions in the default export. I just want to define my functions and then make sure they are exported so I can use them either way.

Suggestions? Or do I have to use `import * as Mod from './my-module';`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can omit the default export and use import as syntax:

```
//app.js
import * as Mod from './my-module'
import { funcA, funcB } from './my-module'

console.log('A', Mod.funcA(), funcA()); // A a a
console.log('B', Mod.funcB(), funcB()); // B b b
```

```
//my-module.js
export function funcA() { return 'a'; };
export function funcB() { return 'b'; };
```

Comment: So the `import Mod from ’./my-module‘` is not to be used in the way asked above?

Comment: It *can* be used as above, but I see no reason for the duplication of `funcA`/`funcB` in the default export

Answer (score 5):

Import entire module's contents once using `* as name`:

```
import * as Mod from './my-module';
```

Then assign them to separate constants using destructuring:

```
const { funcA, funcB } = Mod;
```

For export just use the named exports:

```
export function funcA() { return 'a'; };
export function funcB() { return 'b'; };
```