# React failed to compile Module not found: Can't resolve on listingDetail

Tags: reactjs, react-router

> I am getting error on react that say failed to compile and ./src/App.js
>
> > I notice that on route exact path "ListingDetail" got yellow highlight and others are blue highlight
> > Module not found: Can't resolve './containers/ListingDetail'

[image]

Comment: Can you share how `ListingDetail` is exported?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript Or this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569961/es6-default-and-named-exports

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the way you export the component.

Let me explain, In React we use the keyword export to export a particular module or a named parameter or a combination.

**Exporting default export**

```
export default ListingDetail;
```

This is to export the whole component as default.

**Exporting named values**

```
export { PARA_NAME }
```

Every component can have several named parameters and in order to export one we should use the upper syntax

Here you wanted to export the whole component; then you need to use the 1st approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my own error that the file was save as ListingsDetail.js so I took s off to save as ListingDetail.js